# Check for nested attributes in before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

When you submit a form to the controller for saving in ActiveRecord, you can add missing fields via `@foo.field = 'bar'`. I would like to do the same thing for a nested attribute, but I cannot figure out how.

I am trying to do something like:

```
'@foo.bar.field = 'baz'
```

where the foo model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar
```

if that makes more sense.

Edit: relevant model code

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...  

  has_many :update

  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :update, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:body].blank?}

  ...
end
```

Update model

```
class Update < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
  belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => 'product_id'

  geocoded_by :address
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude

  validates :body, :presence => true

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ((params[:product])["update_attributes"])["0"].merge!({"user_id" => u_id})
```

long winded, but that solved it

Answer (score 1):

```
@foo.bar.field = 'baz'
```

is not about `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. You can add `before_save` validation into `Bar` model and then it will perfectly work with:

```
bar = @foo.bar
bar.field = "baz"
bar.save
# => now before_save will be executed
```

Via `accepts_nested_attributes_for` it will looks like that:

```
@foo.bar_attributes = { :id => XXX, :field => "baz" }
@foo.save
```

In this case you should add validation into `Foo` model

Comment: This is giving me an error undefined method to_i for :integer_field when I do @product.update_attributes = { :integer_field => '1' }. I do not call to_i, so I'm assuming its implicit..

Comment: why are you talking about `@product.update_attributes`? Show your model code

Comment: I will post the model code. What I am trying to do is add a missing field to a nested form before saving it, however. The value for that field has to be accessed from the controller, as it does not exist in the model.

Comment: 1. RENAME YOUR `Update` MODEL! 2. you can't set `has_many :update` but `has_many :updates` so you will get `accepts_nested_attributes_for :updates` and `@product.updates_attributes = {...}`

Comment: I understand the convention is to use the plural here, but I need to work with the singular. has_many :update works fine, similarly, the issue is not with the lack of an 's' when using @product.update_attributes, but rather that to_i is being implicitly called for no good reason

Comment: and I HAVE to use it, no choice. It was chosen by another dev